# `xymatrix` arrow labels compiles incorrectly or does not compile

Tags: labels, subscripts, superscripts, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

Update: added detail as per @Christoph Frings comments!

I am trying to draw a commutative-style diagram using xymatrix and could not find a post detailing the same issue I have.

I have used: `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` in my preamble to port the package. Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=1.0cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, includehead, includefoot}
\title{x}
\author{y}
\date{}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}[section]
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\dee}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Dee}{\mathrm{D}}
\newcommand{\pee}{\mathrm{p}}
\newcommand{\arr}{\mathrm{r}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
```

I am trying to draw the following: [image]

and using Milne's guide, I have written:

```
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
    (\Z/n\Z)^\times \ar[dr]_{\mod f} \ar[rr]^{\chi} & & \C \\
    & (\Z/f\Z)^\times \ar[ur]_{\tilde{\chi}} & }
\end{document}
```

and this will not compile, quoting errors for multiple superscripts/subscripts.

The closest I can output to this diagram is the following, which seems to place the mod label in the completely wrong position, using the following code:

```
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
(\Z/n\Z)^\times \ar[dr]_{\mod f} \ar[rr] & & \C \\
& (\Z/f\Z)^\times \ar[ur] & }
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I fix this error and hopefully get this package to work properly?!

Thank you so much in advance and apologies if this is a silly question!

Comment: Please post a complete working code (specially since you use non standard macros as \Z and \C). Even completed with relevant preamble your code gives an unwanted result since you decided to replace linebreaks with ;. It is not useful, linebreaks are (almost) irrelevant in LaTeX and I had to edit your snippet to test it. Once I did all that your code compiled just fine.

Comment: Plus you can use `\ast` instead of `\times` to get the asterix.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much for your comment! I'll try and implement these changes now. I used ; to denote a linebreak because I did not know how to implement lines in the code environment for stackexchange.

Comment: Post has been updated, and the drawing still will not compile as the drawing should indicate - could there be some sort of conflicting package?

Comment: The problem is with `breqn` which is not compatible with `xy`. Get rid of it, it has been experimental for 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

I have reduced your long code and I have done a MWE that works correctly to have the first picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
    (\Z/n\Z)^{\ast} \ar[dr]_{\mod f} \ar[rr]^{\chi} & & \C \\
    & (\Z/f\Z)^{\ast}\ar[ur]_{\tilde{\chi}} & }
\end{document}
```

[image]

**My suggestions**: You check if have an updated version of `LaTeX` and deleted one to one the package to see eventual problems.